# Linked issuetypes of an issue and with status as Cancelled

Tags: jira, jql

How do combine these two queries in JIRA.

I want to get list of enablers under user stories that are with staus as CANCELLED

```
and issuetype = Enabler  AND  issueFunction  in linkedIssuesOf("Status='CANCELLED'") 

and issuetype = Enabler  AND  issueFunction  in linkedIssuesOf("type='User Story'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply chain 'issueFunction's like:

```
and issuetype = Enabler  AND  issueFunction  in linkedIssuesOf("Status='CANCELLED'") AND issueFunction  in linkedIssuesOf("type='User Story'")
```